# Primes with many zeros

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider numbers of the form
\begin{align}
p\equiv p_{a,b,n}&=a\times10^{n+1+\lfloor \log_{10}(b) \rfloor}+b\\
&=a\, \underbrace{0\cdots 0}_\text{$n$ zeros}  \,b,
\end{align}
where $a,b,n\in\mathbb{N}$. For any $a,b$ (with $b$ odd and not ending in $5$), are there infinitely prime numbers of such form?

I've computed a few simple cases, for $n\leq 2000$,
\begin{align}
a= 1,b=1 &\Rightarrow n\in\{   1 \}\\
a= 2,b= 1&\Rightarrow n\in\{    \}\\
a= 3,b= 1&\Rightarrow n\in\{2, 6, 9, 27, 35, 66, 80, 146, 482, 642, 1019, 1899  \}\\
a= 4,b= 1&\Rightarrow n\in\{  1, 2, 12, 228, 241, 308, 956, 1472, 1493 \}\\
a= 9,b=1 &\Rightarrow n\in\{  2, 3, 4, 8, 21, 26, 35, 56, 61, 77, 200, 536, 695, 789, 904, 1037  \}\\
a=1 ,b= 3&\Rightarrow n\in\{   1, 4, 5, 10, 16, 17, 38, 55, 100, 104, 106, 122, 412, 425 \}\\
a=3 ,b=3 &\Rightarrow n\in\{    \}\\
a=4 ,b=3 &\Rightarrow n\in\{  2, 6, 9, 39, 418, 448, 1736  \}\\
a=1 ,b=7 &\Rightarrow n\in\{ 1, 3, 7, 8, 23, 59, 109, 133, 221, 411, 699, 998, 1382   \}\\
a=2 ,b=7 &\Rightarrow n\in\{    \}\\
a= 4,b=7 &\Rightarrow n\in\{ 2, 8, 38  \}\\
a= 5,b=7 &\Rightarrow n\in\{    \}\\
a= 8,b=7 &\Rightarrow n\in\{    \}\\
a= 1,b= 9&\Rightarrow n\in\{ 1, 2, 3, 8, 17, 21, 44, 48, 55, 68, 145, 201, 271 \}\\
a=2 ,b=9 &\Rightarrow n\in\{ 4, 24, 454, 760 \}\\
a=4 ,b=9 &\Rightarrow n\in\{ 1, 3, 4, 7, 8, 27, 190, 195 \}
\end{align}
Some of these cases are relatively easy to show that there are not infinitely many such primes (for example $30\cdots 0 3$ is always a multiple of $10\cdots 01$), but some are rather intriguing, like $40\cdots 07$. Are these finite?

Any ideas or insights are appreciated.

Comment: Clearly if $3\mid a+b$ there will be no such primes.

Comment: These types of problems are notoriously hard.  I don't think there are any sequences of the form $a c^n + b$ with $a,b,c$ integers with say $a>0$ and $c>1$ that are known to have infinitely many primes, nor are there any such sequences known to contain a finite number other than $0$. Based on the prime number theorem we expect most but not all such sequences to either always be divisible by some fixed prime or to contain infinitely many primes. But there are definitely exceptions, for example the sequence $2^n+1$ is expected to only have finitely many primes.

Comment: We can expect infinite many such primes, but a proof almost surely is out of reach.

Comment: the $a=4;b=7$ sequence requires an even number of 0's otherwise it divides by 11.